# How to exclude a pattern of directories from being indexed by PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I am doing a massive (next-major-version) refactoring of an ecosystem that involves a heapload of packages.

In this stage, all packages are loaded from a `path` (`packages/*`) repo. Thus, all packages, when required, are symlinked into the requiring package `vendor` directory. This creates eventually a nested `vendor/<vendor>/<package>/vendor/<vendor>/<other_package>/.....` structure. PhpStorm tries to index all of this.

I have two problems with it:

1. It takes forever
2. It throws off static inspection: finds multiple implementations of the same class (because in depth there are multiple symlinks to the same package). It can find some ghost definitions of a class in a forgotten `vendor` directory that will not actually be present when doing a clean composer install without symlinks.

Is there a way to exclude `vendor/*/*/vendor/` from indexing?

Comment: `Settings/Preferences | Directories` and mark unwanted folders as Excluded. Or do the same right from the Project View panel via right click menu. In both cases -- one folder at a time. OR exclude some parent folder.

Comment: @LazyOne tried that, I've set the whole root `vendor` to excluded, it still resolves class references down the depths of misteryland

Comment: Check `Settings/Preferences | PHP` --> `Include Paths`. By default all Composer packages are individually excluded and then re-added back there (so the IDE can offer code completion from those packages but do not treat them as the project code itself (so will not report TODOs/inspections/do renaming there).

Comment: By configuring `composer.json` under `composer` I see an improvement in static resolution of class references, but not in indexing: every time I add a new dependency to the root, and that has its `vendor/...` symlinked to other symlinked libraries ect, the indexing time goes to about 10 minutes and growing with each such dependency (which figures, because a fully connected graph is O(n^2)... ). I do see all `vendor/...` dependencies excluded in `Directories`.

Comment: What's worse, it seems completely oblivious of the symlinks and the fact that `vendor/prov/lib1` and `vendor/prov/lib2/vendor/prov/lib1` are the same library, so the search space can explode exponentially. Probably infinitely if I add a circular dependency which composer allows :)

Comment: *"What's worse, it seems completely oblivious of the symlinks"* Consider voting for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-256182 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127022

Comment: Ah, so it's a known issue...

Comment: Yes, the IDE works with the file system as is, which means that files in symlinked folders will be treated as different ones.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
No matter what I´ve excluded in some settings, it didn´t worked as intented.
Deactivating "indexer.follows.symlinks" in the registry only worked sometimes (for unknown reasons).

The plugin "Exclude Symlinks" finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up writing a composer plugin that, in the `.idea/*.xml` files:

- `<component name="ComposerSettings" updatePackages="false">` in `workspace.xml`
- Adds an `<excludeFolder>` for every composer package in `project.iml/module/component/content`
- Adds `<sourceFolder>`s for every package source root(s) based on the package's `composer.json` `autoload` section in `project.iml/module/component/content`

This seems a sensible workaround for the moment... although it's fragile with respect to changing package source paths, most packages have only one source root, `src` and that isn't likely to change any time soon.